# Add class and tag to span using execCommand

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When a user selects the text and clicks the `Add Annotation` button then selected text is moved into the next div and wrapped in a span with the selected color background using `execCommand()`.

How can I add a class and a `<sup>` tag to the span?

[Sample JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/indianwebdesigner/51Ljwygc/1/)

```
function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    var range, sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

function remove_selection() {
    if (document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    }
}

function highlight(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    colour = $('.colors .active').find('a').attr('class');
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE <= 8 case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();

    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

$('.annotation-button').on('click touchend', function () {
    selected_text = getSelectionText();
    var list_count = selected_text.length;
    annotation_color = $('.annotation-select').data('color');
    if (list_count > 0) {
        $('.added-annotation ul').append('<li class="' + annotation_color + '"><p class="content">' + selected_text + '</p></li>');
    }
    selection_length = 0;
    var list_length = $('#annotation-form .added-annotation li');
    var i = 1;
    list_length.each(function (element) {
        $(this).find('span').html(i);
        i++;
    });

    highlight();
    remove_selection();

});

$('.colors a').click(function () {
    $('.colors li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
    $('.annotation-select').removeClass('yellow orange red green purple blue')
    var color_name = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.annotation-select').addClass(color_name).data('color', color_name);
    remove_selection();
    return false;
});
```

```css
.colors ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.colors ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
.colors ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.colors a {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    display:block;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #cecece;
}
/*  Colors  */
 .colors .yellow {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
.colors .orange {
    background-color: #ffc000;
}
.colors .red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.colors .green {
    background-color: #70ad47;
}
.colors .purple {
    background-color: #7030a0;
}
.colors .blue {
    background-color: #5b9bd5;
}
/* Text Selection Backgrounds */
 .annotation-select.yellow .description::selection {
    background: #fafa96;
}
.annotation-select.orange .description::selection {
    background-color: #ffc000;
}
.annotation-select.red .description::selection {
    background-color: #fa8989;
}
.annotation-select.green .description::selection {
    background-color: #b2e391;
}
.annotation-select.purple .description::selection {
    background-color: #ca91f5;
}
.annotation-select.blue .description::selection {
    background-color: #bbdbf9;
}
.annotation-select.yellow .description::-moz-selection {
    background: #fafa96;
}
.annotation-select.orange .description::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #ffc000;
}
.annotation-select.red .description::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #fa8989;
}
.annotation-select.green .description::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #b2e391;
}
.annotation-select.purple .description::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #ca91f5;
}
.annotation-select.blue .description::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #bbdbf9;
}
.colors span {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    display: none;
    top: -1px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #242424;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.colors .active span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="yellow">Yellow <span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="orange">Orange <span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="red">Red <span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="green">Green <span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="purple">Voilet <span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="blue">Blue <span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- colors -->
<button type="button" class="annotation-button" >Add Annotation</button>
<hr>
<div class="annotation-select yellow" data-color="yellow">
    <div class="description text-annotate">...</div>
</div>
<div class="added-annotation">
    <ul></ul>        
</div>
```

Comment: Here is Demo (https://jsfiddle.net/indianwebdesigner/51Ljwygc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking or looking for, you need to give more information. You have one problem I see right away and that is int the for loop $(this) refers to the button you clicked on not an existing span.

```
var i = 1;
list_length.each(function(element){
  console.log(this);
  $(this).find('span').html(i);
  i++;
});
```

That having been said I will take a guess at what you are trying to do.  I assume you want to add a superscript number to the right of each span element.  This number will essentially be an index. Maybe this will help you.  Note I haven't used jQuery in many years so my fix will use JavaScript.

Basically I commented out you for loop and added some code after the remove_selection() to add sup tags. First you will have to delete all existing sup tags.  If this is not what you are looking for please give us more information.

```
/*
var i = 1;
list_length.each(function(element){
  console.log(this);
  $(this).find('span').html(i);
  i++;
});
*/


highlight();
remove_selection();

// Get the container
const textAnnotate = document.querySelector('.text-annotate');
// Delete all existing sup tags from container
const nodeListExistingSupTags = textAnnotate.querySelectorAll("sup");
nodeListExistingSupTags.forEach(element => {
  element.remove();
});

// Now add new sup tags and renumber them
const nodeListSpans = textAnnotate.querySelectorAll("span");
for (let i = 0; i < nodeListSpans.length; i++) {
  // Remove trailing space 
  nodeListSpans[i].innerHTML = nodeListSpans[i].innerHTML.trimEnd();
  var sup = document.createElement("sup");
  sup.innerHTML = (i + 1) + " "; // Add index and trailing space
  nodeListSpans[i].appendChild(sup);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Larry_Robertson/vexj5w1h/40/)

Good Luck